# Create GeoTIFF from data array using the original file metadata

Tags: python, gdal, sar

I received a .mat file which is the processed data from a Radarsat-2 scene. My goal is to transform this data array into a GeoTIFF file, onto the same projection as the original Radarsat-2 image.

I used the code provided by @EddyTheB [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57005/python-gdal-write-new-raster-using-projection-from-old?rq=1), but the final result (teste.tif) does not correspond to the desirable output. See Figures below.

Original scene:

[image: Radarsat-2 original scene]

Final result:

[image: Final result]

The no data values in the new figure is part of the processing.

One can find the three files (original SAR scene, the .mat file and the created .tif) in [here](https://filesender.uninett.no/?s=download&token=435a921e-ea33-4c1f-9de9-4ec6e568d1dc). The following code was used:

```py
import scipy.io 
from osgeo import osr, gdal

# Open .mat file
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(dataset1.mat)
mat_values = mat['dataset1']   

# Define file SAR original data
FileName = '04_FQ2_HHVVHVVH_SLC_914865_9114_42814173.tif'

# Function to read the original file's projection:
def GetGeoInfo(FileName):
    SourceDS = gdal.Open(FileName, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    NDV = SourceDS.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
    xsize = SourceDS.RasterXSize
    ysize = SourceDS.RasterYSize
    GeoT = SourceDS.GetGeoTransform()
    Projection = osr.SpatialReference()
    Projection.ImportFromWkt(SourceDS.GetProjectionRef())
    DataType = SourceDS.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
    DataType = gdal.GetDataTypeName(DataType)
    return NDV, xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType

# Function to write a new file.
def CreateGeoTiff(Name, Array, driver, NDV, 
                  xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType):
    if DataType == 'Float32':
        DataType = gdal.GDT_Float32
    NewFileName = Name+'.tif'
    # Set nans to the original No Data Value
    Array[np.isnan(Array)] = NDV
    # Set up the dataset
    DataSet = driver.Create( NewFileName, xsize, ysize, 1, DataType )
            # the '1' is for band 1.
    DataSet.SetGeoTransform(GeoT)
    DataSet.SetProjection( Projection.ExportToWkt() )
    # Write the array
    DataSet.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( Array )
    #DataSet.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(NDV)
    return NewFileName

# Now I'm ready to save the new file, in the meantime I have 
# closed the original, so I reopen it to get the projection
# information...
NDV, xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType = GetGeoInfo(FileName)

# Set up the GTiff driver
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

# Now turn the array into a GTiff.
NewFileName = CreateGeoTiff('teste', mat_values, driver, NDV, 
                            xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection, DataType)
```

**Update**: I was told that 9x9 multilooking was performed before in the original image before updating the values present in the **.mat** file.

Comment: Please remember to always include code in coding questions. You also need to define "desirable output" and describe what you got instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, @Vince. Since I used the same code provided in the link I referenced, I didn't paste here to not make the question too long and messy.

Comment: Well, that's one way to work it, but if no one is willing to follow links (few are), you'll never get an answer. If the code is too long, you may yet need to do the due dilligence of trying to isolate the problem.